# garbage collection of classes with Observables

Tags: garbage-collection, system.reactive

I'm missing something about when and how classes with RX Observable and their ilk are released and garbage collected. The below example is contrived, but the class Test doesn't seem to be freed up by setting the instance to null. When you run it the '.' printer by the Observable are printed long after the test instance set to null.

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to implement IDisposable for every class that uses one?

Here's the console output
Testing
................!
................!
exiting
................................

```
namespace GarbageCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Test
        {
            IObservable<long> ticker;
            public Test()
            {
                ticker = Observable.Interval( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 50 ) );
                ticker.Subscribe( _ => Console.Write( '.' ) );
            }
        }

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Testing");
            var test = new Test();

            while ( ! Console.KeyAvailable )
            {
                Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
                test = null;
                Console.WriteLine( '!' );
            }
            Console.WriteLine( "exiting" );
            Thread.Sleep( 2000 );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Observable.Interval and other timers are one of the few sources that you must explicitly disconnect all subscribers, because it keeps itself alive (i.e. it has this implicit "reference" to the TPL scheduler).

Normally, you can trust that Rx objects will be GC'd normally, you don't have to Dispose all IDisposables or keep track of them.

Comment: I would switch it around. Most of the time you subscribe you should manually unsubscribe. In the case of RXUI and using WhenAny on properties of ``this`` you can get away with avoiding disposing subscriptions because you know the lifetime of the source is the same as the lifetime of the subscriber, ie they are the same object. In general however it's not that easy to tell.